# cleanup sqlite db file on close

Tags: sqlite, spring-boot, jooq

Can we cleanup {filename}.db as soon as prototype bean goes out of scope in spring boot project with jooq starter ?

The destroy method needs to get handle of filename.

Tried putting `;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1` at end of URL but does not seem to work with sqlite files. Expected some value of DB_CLOSE_DELAY that deletes file at end or does it in-memory.

```
@Bean
public Function<String, DSLContext> dslFactory() {
    return this::dsl;
}

@Bean
@Scope("prototype")
@ConfigurationProperties("datasource")
public DefaultDSLContext dsl(String filename) {
    DataSource dataSource = DataSourceBuilder.create()
            .url("jdbc:sqlite:" + filename + ".db")
            .build();

    DefaultConfiguration jooqConfiguration = new DefaultConfiguration();
    jooqConfiguration.set(new DataSourceConnectionProvider(new TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy(dataSource)));
    jooqConfiguration.set(new DefaultExecuteListenerProvider(new ExceptionTranslator()));

    DefaultDSLContext context = new DefaultDSLContext(jooqConfiguration);
    return context;
}
```

Usage :

```
@Autowired
private Function<String, DSLContext> dslFactory;

DSLContext dsl = dslFactory.apply("xxx");
```

Tried overriding in prototype bean declaration `DefaultExecuteListener.end` but it gets called on each `dsl execute()`. Something like below would have been ideal - using lombok cleanup when final dslContext goes out of scope i.e at end of method invocation having `context.getBean/apply` as above, then {filename}.db is deleted.

```
 @Cleanup DefaultDSLContext context = new DefaultDSLContext(jooqConfiguration);
```

Comment: You cannot do this with jOOQ API, because jOOQ doesn't know (or care) about your bean lifecycles. Use Spring's API instead.

Comment: @LukasEder Can we give in memory sqlite files , something like h2 supports using :mem: in url for datasource ? I tried writing a bean post processor for protoype scoped dslContext as in example above but since connection is still open to database from DSLContext , it does not allow deleting .db file.

Comment: That's a rather different question from the one you've asked, and it already has an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8831514/521799

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> That's a rather different question from the one you've asked, and it already has an answer here: stackoverflow.com/q/8831514/521799 – Lukas Eder

According to link provided, we can use `::memory:` at end of url to create in-memory sqlite files, requiring no cleanup otherwise necessary.